# Comparing model DICs across multiple MCMCglmm models

Tags: r, compare

So I'm looking for a quick way to create a table of DIC scores from MCMCglmm models in R. I've run 10 different models and could extract the DIC from each separately using the following code, where the model is called m1:

```
    m1.DIC <- m1$DIC
```

But then I have to do this for each model, and then create the dataframe, which is tedious. I've looked at the documentation for the MCMCglmm package and haven't found any hints about whether I can get a quick summary across models through some built-in function. Is there one? Is there another package that can do this? I know the `rethinking` package uses `compare` to get quick and easy model comparisons, but this doesn't appear to work with MCMCglmm outputs, as I get the following error message:

```
    > compare(m1, m2, WAIC=FALSE)
    Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
    no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "MCMCglmm"
    In addition: Warning message:
    In DIC(z, n = n) :
    No specific DIC method for object of class MCMCglmm. Returning AIC instead. applied to an    object of class "MCMCglmm"
```

Is there a similar method that will work to compare MCMCglmm models?

EDIT: Also note that the `compare` function in `rethinking` calculates weights for the models, from the DIC. Maybe this just doesn't exist in a form that works with the MCMCglmm package.

Comment: anything wrong with putting the fitted objects into a list and using `sapply(model_list,"[[","DIC")` ?

Comment: So I could do that, but it'd still be slower than some kind of `compare` function. The `compare` function also calculates DIC weights which would be nice. Maybe it just doesn't exist in a form that works with the MCMCglmm package.

Comment: why would it be slower? extracting an element from a list hardly takes any effort at all. Or do you mean it'll take you longer to code?

Comment: The latter - I'm comparing a variety of models on a regular basis and it'd be nice to have a function like this available.

Comment: Looks like there are no takers, so I'm using Ben's suggestion above. If I find anything in the future, I'll update the thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to generate and compare a list of possible models from scratch you can use the dredge function in the MuMIn package http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/MuMIn.pdf which supports MCMCglmm objects.

First you need to make the MCMCglmm call updateable though (so that dredge can change the model composition): 
MCMCglmm.updateable<- updateable(MCMCglmm). 
Then you can run your global model: 
global.model<- MCMCglmm.updateable(y~x1+...etc.)
The call to dredge would then be something like 
dredge.MCMCglmm<- dredge(global.model, rank="DIC" ...)
You can also get standardized coefficients and adjusted R^2.

If you already have a list of fitted models you can use model.sel (in the same package) to generate a ranked table with model weights etc:
model.sel(model1, model2, model3, rank="DIC")

Good luck!

Best,
Adrian

Comment: Note: the 'model.sel(model1, model2, rank = "DIC")' function appears not to work for zero-inflated models. I suspect this is because it's a multi-response model. Not sure how to fix this because a simple 'model.name$DIC' does produce the expected output (DIC for that model's named variable). But 'model.sel' results in the following error: 'Error in vapply(models, function(x) nobs(x), 1) : 
  values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[2]]) result is length 2'